# How to use compressed / encoded textures in QML?

Tags: qt, opengl, textures

Is it possible to send to a QImage data from a compressed texture directly in qml?

Right now I'm having the following code :

```
Image 
{
  anchors.fill: parent
  fillMode : Image.Stretch
  source : "Textures/BG_png.png"
}
```

Then, I create images having sources with various formats , more precisely :

```
// uncompressed
source : "Textures/BG_RGB565.dds"
source : "Textures/BG_RGB888.dds"
source : "Textures/BG_RGBA8888.dds"

//compressed
source : "Textures/BG_ETC1.ktx"
source : "Textures/BG_ETC1.pkm"
source : "Textures/BG_ETC1.dds"
source : "Textures/BG_PVR.pvr"
source : "Textures/BG_ASTC.astc"
```

I'm getting the following error "QML Image : invalid image data" for every source type except BG_RGB565.dds (and only with the ".dds" extension).

I the following questions :

1. why does RGB565.dds work and RGB888 or other uncompressed formats don't ?
2. what OpenGL image types do QT QML support, and how do you hint the Image class that it's source is encoded / compressed in a certain way using QML only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement this yourself using a QQuickImageProvider.

Set the QQuickImageProvider's type to:

```
QQmlImageProviderBase::Texture
```

Then return a `QSGTextureProvider` from `requestTexture(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)`

See more details here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html

Currently the only supported formats that Image {} supports is:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html

It might be possible to load it from Qt3D, but I'm not sure if these formats are supported.

Comment: As stated in the documentation dds doesn't support 3rd part codex. Which means that ETC1 compression isn't supported.